# Error inflating class fragment.

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2

Tried so many times to avoid this error bus still can't find the answer to this.
This is my first app with google APIs. and I wanted to just display the map on the screen. I get the "inflating class fragment" error and tried so many solutions I found, but still I get the same error. please help !

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.testmap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testmap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testmap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAo7D5KmWcB8hdw6QZ_xxxxxxxxxxlv6m0" />
<!--add your api here as android:value -->


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you add the exception stack trace as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have `write` to external storage permission so add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in your permissions

Answer (score 0):

Replace your fragment tag with the following

```
<fragment 
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

As far as I know of, MapFragment is for older API versions.

Comment: but `android:minSdkVersion="14"` then it's fine to used `MapFragment`